# How to find the minimum of a noisy function that has very narrow valleys?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, gradient-descent

I am trying to find a set of optimum parameters of my model that provide the best fit. I chose to make this into an optimization problem where I minimize my $\chi^2$ per degree of freedom and try to find the parameters for the minimum $\chi^2$. The dependence of $\chi^2$ on one of my parameters looks like the following:
[image: Plot of $\chi^2$ against parameter $\dot{f}$]

As you can see, the dependence is very very noisy and the minimum presents as a very narrow valley. To find this minimum, I tried gradient descent only to realize that because the valley is very narrow, my gradient is going to be very large and even with a tiny learning rate, I move significantly away from my initial point thereby failing to work.

Then I thought maybe Newton's method would do but again realized that it would suffer the same issue. The first derivative, if we're already very close to the valley would be large and the second derivative would very likely be 0 or very close to 0, thereby failing again. My code moves from the starting point to a far away point just like in gradient descent.

So I was wondering if there is a method that might work for my case. I do know the starting point pretty well and right now I'm brute-forcing my way through it, where I choose a large number of points around my starting point and calculate $\chi^2$ for all of them and find the minimum but that is not very efficient.

Comment: Is it a function that really is that noisy (but it's deterministic and you can evaluate it exactly wherever you want), or is the graph you're showing a measured result? In the latter case you might as well just look for the smallest measurement ...

Comment: The former. My function is really just the $\chi^2$ value I get after making a fit with my parameter $\dot{f}$. So I can evaluate it for any value of $\dot{f}$. The plot above is of $\chi^2$ for my fit versus $\dot{f}$.

Comment: Why not just magnify the plot and read where the minimum is?

Comment: I need to do it algorithmically. This is part of a machinery to detect a certain model in a noisy signal and this needs to be automated so that it can keep looking for the model in the continuous signal.

Comment: Use a (non-causal) low-pass filter to smooth the graph. Then use numerical differentiation to find the minimum. Do not forget about the 2nd derivative test.

Comment: I used a non-causal low-pass filter and it smooths the graph pretty well. How do I find the minimum then? I tried using gradient decent on the smoothed graph but I get stuck on local minima.

Comment: Do numerical differentiation. Find where the numerical derivative is close to zero (in absolute value). Check if the 2nd derivative is positive. List all local minima and find the smallest one.